# Why am I reciving a 403 error when trying to authorize Apps Script with the Tumblr api?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, tumblr

I'm completely new to oauth and APIs, and I'm trying to use some [example apps script oauth code](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/Basecamp.gs) for accessing the Basecamp API to create a post on Tumblr:

```
var npfPost = {
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Hello world!"
        }
    ]
}

function run() {
  var service = getService_();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog_id}.tumblr.com/posts';
    var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
      npfPost,

      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            }
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        'https://' + authorizationUrl);
  }
}


function reset() {
  getService_().reset();
}

function getService_() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Tumblr')
      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('www.tumblr.com/oauth2/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('api.tumblr.com/v2/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)

      // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
      // complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getService_();
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
  }
}

function logRedirectUri() {
  Logger.log(OAuth2.getRedirectUri());
}
```

I've successfully generated an authorization url, which I expected to send me straight to the authCallback function after I authorized access. Instead I get the following error from apps script:

```
Error: Error retrieving token: 403: {"meta":{"status":403,"msg":"Forbidden"},"response":[],"errors":[{"title":"Forbidden","code":5006,"detail":"A secure connection (https) is required to access the Tumblr API"}]} (line 605, file "Service")
```

What part of my connection do I need to secure?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, when you add `https://` to the URLs of `.setAuthorizationBaseUrl('www.tumblr.com/oauth2/authorize')` and `.setTokenUrl('api.tumblr.com/v2/oauth2/token')` in your script, the error message will be changed?

Comment: Good catch, that did the trick! Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this case, I thought that the solution might be useful for other users. So, I posted it as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OP's reply of `Good catch, that did the trick! Thank you so much`, I understood that my guess was the correct way to resolve OP's issue. In this case, I thought that the solution might be useful for other users. So, I posted it as the following answer.

In this modification, the issue was resolved by adding `https://` as follows.

#### From:

```
.setAuthorizationBaseUrl('www.tumblr.com/oauth2/authorize')
.setTokenUrl('api.tumblr.com/v2/oauth2/token')
```

#### To:

```
.setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/oauth2/authorize')
.setTokenUrl('https://api.tumblr.com/v2/oauth2/token')
```